# Partial forking of OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I am currently developing an image processing application using OpenCV's *cxcore* as the basic structure (Matrix class and the their functions are very convenient). However, I don't really use the image processing capabilities provided by OpenCV (*cv* and *cvaux*). All I need is the *cxcore* module, and some *highgui* for debugging purpose.

Is it possible to fork openCV's *cxcore* into my own project, legally and technically? Have anyone ever done this before? My intention is to have my application be able to be compiled in any system without having to install openCV as an intermediate step.

Thanks :-) ,
Andree

P.S.: I have posted the same question in OpenCV's mailing list.

Comment: If you only need the matrices, wouldn't the Eigen library do a better job for you? It has three megabytes and it produces somewhat nicer messages for type errors. You would have to do the debugging by another library, however. (Edit: aha, the question is this old. OK.)

Answer (score 1):

Since OpenCV is licensed with BSD license, you should be able to do *anything* to the code, even regardless of whether your application is proprietary or free software. *Anything* includes using only part of that code in your application.

That being said, sharing won't hurt you and it's nice and polite :)